# SQL List previous sales of dates in the current month

Tags: sql

[image]

[image]

On the sql side, as seen in the table below, I want to subtract the sale of the day before today's date and have it printed in a separate column.

example; Subtract the sale on 2022-04-17 from the sale on 2022-04-18 and write it in the side column.

subtract the sales from the previous day until you find the last date in the table in a loop.

Comment: please provide sample data in the text format. Have you read about LAG-function ?

Comment: What's your dbms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `LEAD` window function with `CASE WHEN` expression

```
SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN LEAD(n_Sales) OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerId,ProductId ORDER BY Date DESC) IS NULL 
        THEN Sales ELSE 
        Sales - LEAD(n_Sales) OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerId,ProductId ORDER BY Date DESC) 
    END
FROM T
```